# How to add icon image to a row in wpf devexpress gridcontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

Is it possible to have an icon image on each row of a devexpress gridcontrol based on the row's value? If yes, how? I've been searching for a while and all i could find is how to change background/foreground colors of the row based on a value. But i really need an icon.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q454886